# Android In-App Billing Version 3 - Server-side Verification

Tags: php, android, in-app-billing

I'm making Android Application with In-App Purchases. On [Android Developer Center page](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-security) I see that I must verify purchase data (json) with signature. I trying to use [PHP tool from Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/android-market-license-verification/source/browse/trunk/library/AndroidMarket/Licensing/) for this, but validation failed. First fail be that this library want from me not json (as I understand), but some plain text with fields, joined with `:` and `|`. It split this plain string to get `packageName` and validate it too. I commented this part of code, because next part more interesting:

```
$result = openssl_verify($responseData, base64_decode($signature),
  $this->_publicKey, self::SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM);

//openssl_verify returns 1 for a valid signature
if (0 === $result) {
    return false;
} else if (1 !== $result) {
    require_once 'RuntimeException.php';
    throw new AndroidMarket_Licensing_RuntimeException('Unknown error verifying the signature in openssl_verify');
}
```

where `$responseData` is my purchase json, `self::SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM` is `OPENSSL_ALGO_SHA1`, `$this->_publicKey` is:

```
$key = self::KEY_PREFIX . chunk_split($publicKey, 64, "\n") . self::KEY_SUFFIX;
$key = openssl_get_publickey($key);
if (false === $key) {
    require_once 'InvalidArgumentException.php';
    throw new AndroidMarket_Licensing_InvalidArgumentException('Please pass a Base64-encoded public key from the Market portal');
}
$this->_publicKey = $key;
```

where public key is base64 public key, like described:

```
Note:To find the public key portion of this key pair, open your application's
details in the Developer Console, then click on Services & APIs, and look at the
field titled Your License Key for This Application.
```

But such verification is fail. I read that API 3 is new (Dec 2012), and many other articles and tutorials isn't correspond to it. What I need to change to correct this verification?

This code using SHA1, but on Android Developer Center page (first link) described that public key is RSA with X.509... Any ideas?

**UPD**: While trying to make server always say 'purchase is ok' and add all purchases to database, find that this error is my fail. I take json to server in base64, since on server i `base64_decode` it in two different places, so I breaking it. This library works in part of code that use openssl to validate json. Previos version, as I understand, just validate package name; this may be easy rewrited to read `productId` from json.

Comment: So how did you managed to verify JSON {"orderId":"...",
"packageName":"...","productId":"test_02","purchaseTime":1368638654000,"purchaseState":0,"purchaseToken":"tilkecvfnyrndrvovftczate"}]} against received signature? As I see this lib can't work with this.

Comment: Can you paste your full method for signature validation as I am having the same problems. This is what I am trying to use but still no luck: https://gist.github.com/prime31/4750744. And I noticed it looks very much like your code, I don't know if the key prefixes and suffixes are the same. Thanks!